# Saving Multiple Records In DB - One To Many Relationship

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I want to save my `TicketInvoice` and it's `TicketInvoiceItems` data in database, When I submit my Invoice form, `TicketInvoice` data store in `DB` but `TicketInvoiceItems` data store as null whether I fill it or not, also i have dynamic fields for `TicketInvoiceItems` because `TicketInvoice` `hasMany()` `TicketInvoiceItems`, So no matter how many fields row I add, fill & submit, only one row record store in `DB`, and as I said above, all Items fields store as null.

Here is my `store` method of `TicketInvoiceController`:

```js
public function store(Request $request) {
  $ticketInvoiceItems = collect();

  $ticketInvoiceItems - > push(new TicketInvoiceItems([
    'ticket_invoice_id' => $request['ticket_invoice_id'],
    'passenger_name' => $request['passenger_name'],
    'ticket_no' => $request['ticket_no'],
    'departure_date' => $request['departure_date'],
    'fares' => $request['fares'],
    'sub_total' => $request['sub_total']
  ]));

  $ticketInvoice = TicketInvoice::create([
    'vendor_id' => $request['vendor_id'],
    'ticket_invoice_no' => $request['ticket_invoice_no'],
    'ticket_invoice_date' => $request['ticket_invoice_date'],
    'ticket_invoice_fares_total' => $request['ticket_invoice_fares_total'],
    'ticket_invoice_grand_total' => $request['ticket_invoice_grand_total'],
  ]);

  $ticketInvoice - > ticketInvoiceItems() - > saveMany($ticketInvoiceItems);
}
```

Here is my `VueJs` Code, I didn't know if i made any mistakes here please review it:

```js
< script >
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        ticketInvoices: {},
        vendors: null,
        form: new Form({
          id: "",
          vendor_id: "",
          ticket_invoice_no: "",
          ticket_invoice_date: "",
          ticket_invoice_fares_total: "",
          ticket_invoice_grand_total: "",

          ticketInvoiceItems: [{
            id: "",
            ticket_invoice_id: "",
            passenger_name: "",
            ticket_no: "",
            departure_date: "",
            fares: "",
            sub_total: ""
          }]
        })
      };
    },

    methods: {
      createTicketInvoice() {
        this.form
          .post("api/ticket-invoice")
          .then(() => {
            Fire.$emit("RefreshTable");
          })
          .catch(() => {
            swal("Failed!", "There was something wrong.", "warning");
          });
      },

      addItems() {
        this.form.ticketInvoiceItems.push({
          id: "",
          ticket_invoice_id: "",
          passenger_name: "",
          ticket_no: "",
          departure_date: "",
          fares: "",
          sub_total: ""
        });
      },
      removeItems(pos) {
        this.form.ticketInvoiceItems.splice(pos, 1);
      },
      <
      /script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer...

I'm not accessing the `TicketInvoiceItems` data correctly in the request. I'm currently doing:

```js
$ticketInvoiceItems - > push(new TicketInvoiceItems([
  'ticket_invoice_id' => $request['ticket_invoice_id'],
  'passenger_name' => $request['passenger_name'],
  'ticket_no' => $request['ticket_no'],
  'departure_date' => $request['departure_date'],
  'fares' => $request['fares'],
  'sub_total' => $request['sub_total']
]));
```

But my request data I'm sending back from the front end has all of this wrapped up in an array of `ticketInvoiceItems`.

So i need to do something like:

```js
foreach($request['ticketInvoiceItems'] as $invoiceItem) {
  $ticketInvoiceItems - > push(new TicketInvoiceItems([
    'ticket_invoice_id' => $invoiceItem['ticket_invoice_id'],
    'passenger_name' => $invoiceItem['passenger_name'],
    'ticket_no' => $invoiceItem['ticket_no'],
    'departure_date' => $invoiceItem['departure_date'],
    'fares' => $invoiceItem['fares'],
    'sub_total' => $invoiceItem['sub_total']
  ]));
}
```

Also I'm explicitly setting `'ticket_invoice_id'` on the `TicketInvoiceItems` as this will get populated by the `saveMany()` method.